# How to upload an Excel file and then print that Excel file in vb.net (ADODB)?

Tags: vb.net, connection

In a form I have made 2 buttons and a datagridview field. Actually I want to first upload an Excel file which is then showed in datagridview field and when I click the second button i.e. print button it should print the data present in the Excel workbook.

I am having some issues with the connections i.e. ADODB and OleDb connections.

Comment: Your question is too vague.  *"i am having some issues"* doesn't help us.  You need to explain EXACTLY what you're doing and EXACTLY what happens when you do it.

Comment: Please be specific to things that you want help from others.

Comment: show please your current code